# Finding image resolution?

Tags: resolution, pixel

The picture that I need to use is 240mm x 240mm, with 120 pixels in each direction. Apparently this resolution is somehow good enough for an-in-depth MRI brain scan, so my college lab is asking me to calculate it's resolution. I know that the formula for resolution is meters/number of pixels, but I calculated 2mm for the resolution, and I do not think that is correct. What am I doing wrong?

edit:
The question asks what the image resolution in pixel size is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate it as follows:

120 pixels per 240 mm is 0.5 pixel per mm. (120/240)

Resolution is defined as dots per inch (DPI).
0.5 pixel per mm is 12.7 pixels per inch (0.5 x 25.4 mm)

So your resolution is 12.7 DPI.
Not much but apparently good enough for MRI.

Comment: They ask: "What is the image resolution (pixel size)?". What does this mean and does this still apply?

Comment: The resolution is 12.7 DPI (see above). If they really want to know how big a pixel is then it is 2 mm wide. 0.5 pixel per mm is 1 pixel per 2 mm. However resolution is always measured in DPI.